# How to combine multiple rows connected with a common id into one row after retrieving from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I will really appreciate if the community can help me with the following problem that I have not been able to solve.

The data retrieved from mysql after performing the query is in this format:

```
id    |  invdate       |   product  |  total  |  amountpaid  |  balance
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1        01/04/2015       choco      10000        2000         8000
1        01/04/2015       choco      10000        5000         3000
2        03/04/2015       apple       5000        1000         4000
2        03/04/2015       apple       5000        2000         2000
```

The mysql query that I have used is as follows for the above result:

```
SELECT tprojects.grand_total AS gtot, payments.amount_paid AS apaid, payments.balance AS bal, tprojects.CreatedDate, tprojects.IdProject, tprojects.product, tprojects.vat, tprojects.vtf, tprojects.ProjectStatus, tclients.Company FROM tprojects INNER JOIN payments ON payments.projectid = tprojects.IdProject INNER JOIN tclients ON tclients.IdClient = tprojects.client_id
```

So how would I make the result of the query to be the following in order to be printed for viewing purposes:

```
id|  invdate         |   product   |  total  |  amountpaid  |  balance
1        01/04/2015        choco     10000       7000          3000 
2        03/04/2015        apple      5000       3000          2000
```

I would really appreciate the community's help in this regard. I have been at this for the past 2 days.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id, invdate, product, total, sum(amountpaid), total - sum(amountpaid)
  from invoices
  group by id, invdate, product, total;
```

[example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa4e1/1)

Note this won't work properly if an invoice has more than one product on it - but your schema isn't really setup to handle these cases very well. In fact it could be a lot better set up in general.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well currently I am just putting one product for one invoice. But, there can be multiple payments for one invoice, meaning a person can pay in parts. That was the reason for combining the number of payments for the particular invoice

Comment: well the above solution will work for that use case scenario, but will obviously have to change if you refactor your database at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `group by` and `sum` 
Below query may help you

```
SELECT tprojects.IdProject,tprojects.CreatedDate,tprojects.product,tprojects.grand_total AS gtot, 
SUM(payments.amount_paid) AS apaid, (tprojects.grand_total - SUM(payments.amount_paid)) AS bal
FROM tprojects 
INNER JOIN payments ON payments.projectid = tprojects.IdProject 
INNER JOIN tclients ON tclients.IdClient = tprojects.client_id
GROUP BY tprojects.IdProject
```

Comment: Thanks boss. Your response helped me as well